# JSF 2.2 with Spring Webflow 2.3.1 components not rendered

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsf-2, richfaces, spring-webflow

I'm struggling a bit with migrating an application to JSF 2.2 (with Richfaces 4.0) and Spring Webflow 2.3.1

The server ( Tomcat 6/7) is starting without any error but is only displaying the jsf component code.
Does anyone know where I can find some hints to solve this error?

The Image shows the result of the start page of the application

[image: Result]

Comment: Do you really mean JSF 2.2, or is it 2.0? You've tagged the post with 2.0, but mention 2.2. The latter one is still in beta, so you could expect some breakages (I personally tried a simple page and that one did work on 2.2).

Comment: Where/what exactly is the error/exception thrown? Or is the markup you've shown here all that's displayed in the browser?

Comment: Can you paste the contents of web.xml and the url of the page?

Comment: From where are you migrating? Jsf1? Jsp? .Net? C++? All these cases would need different treatment. Any more information about the case would help, like cited above.

Comment: @Mike Braun: Yes I mean 2.2. 2.0 is not working as well. The tag was added by the editor. Simple pages work without problems, but we have to migrate a huge application...

Comment: @kolossus: No error is thrown. The markup is displayed like shown above and there is no additional info in the logs.

Comment: @Seitaridis: I will paste some once I return to my workplace on monday

Comment: @mico: I'm migrating from JSF 1.2.

Comment: @Hache, there's no tomcat 6/7. It's either tomcat 6 or tomcat 7. As far as I know, tomcat 6.0.X does not readily support JSF 2, tomcat 7 does. If you're deploying in tomcat 6, expect some pain like you see here

Comment: @kolossus: I meant that I tested with both. I'm aware of this but on Tomcat 7 it looks completely the same.

Answer (score 2):

So some how it was never passed through the framework.

Is your faces-config correct? Investigate syntax errors / difference for jsf 2.2.

what about url? are you using /faces/ or .jsf to pass it through the framework? Double check that configuration in web.xml.

Comment: Yes that is correct. The faces servlet is configured to use /faces/ But the front controller is not the faces servlet, we are using the webflow centric approach.